# How to resolve gap in my content div?

Tags: css

I have a **"content div"** and **inside it** there are two div's with background images (gradient and shadow). Now I have a following problem if there is a **lot** of content I have to resize my **"content div"** but when I do that a **BIG GAP** shows between my div's (top and bottom divs). I know i can solve it by inserting a bigger images, but it is a no go for me because I must resize images **every time** when the content div gets bigger.

Is there a any way to solve this? **Thank you guy's!!!**

[Fiddle **WITH LESS CONTENT**](http://jsfiddle.net/9T4PF/) (Haven't resized div so it look's good)

[Fiddle **WITH MORE CONTENT**](http://jsfiddle.net/CDMZT/) Resized my **"content div"** and there is a gap in the middle :(

HTML Code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<meta name="author" content="Dejan Peic"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="mainwrap">
<div class="content">
<p><b>LESS CONTENT LOOKS OK!!!</p>
<div class="top">
</div>

<div class="bottom">
</div>
</div><!--/content-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px}

.content{
background-color:white;
position:relative;
display:block;
width:995px;
height:528px;
margin:0px auto;
margin-top:40px;
margin-bottom:40px;
z-index:100;
overflow:hidden;
}

.top{
position:absolute;
z-index:-100;
background-image:url('http://www.robertpeic.com/Global%20one/template/content-top.png');
top:0;
width:990px;
height:203px;
background-size: contain;
}

.bottom{
position:absolute;
z-index:-100;
background-image:url('http://www.robertpeic.com/Global%20one/template/content-bottom.png');
bottom:0;
width:989px;
height:225px;
background-size: contain;
}

p{
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:20px;
font-size:25px;
}
```

Comment: 1) You could set the container to a fixed size and have a vertical scroll inside it 2) You can have a repeating background for the content 3) You could recreate the shadow without images, using only css, and this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the background image into three parts rather than two:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Place all your content in the middle `div`, then give it a background image that repeats vertically (`background-repeat: repeat-y`). When the amount of content increases, the middle `div` will get taller and the background will repeat vertically to match, so you'll never end up with a gap.

Answer (score 0):

Your heights (`top` and `bottom`) don't add up to 528px in the larger container; however, they do add up to 428 in the smaller one.

If there's any way to eliminate the need for a defined height in your CSS, you may want to pursue it -- to help eliminate quirks like this.